# How to (pinch) zoom on a specific div that has multiple images in an asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, zooming, imagemap, pinchzoom

I am making a web application that has a top menu bar, and a bottom data bar, and in the middle is a div with an imageMap with multiple images displayed over it. I want to make the area with the imageMap pinch zoomable so I can zoom in on the imageMap and smaller images while keeping the rest of the page the same size. I have looked at similar questions and solutions but they either don't work, or only apply to a single image, which I have gotten to work, but I need the entire div to zoom, not just the image.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try using this css code on your element

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 540px;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

if you have several div's in your main div 
just change the class name for other div's and use different value for the class's

Comment: do I need to include any other scripts?

Comment: I tried using what you gave me and couldn't get it to work, I am confused as to why I wouldn't need anything looking for 'pinch' events or something like that.

Comment: That only zooms in when its clicked, what I'm trying to do is enable a pinch zoom on an entire div